# Evaluate: $\int \frac{{\sin(x)}}{{\sin(x) - \cos(x)}}\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, solution-verification, indefinite-integrals

I'm trying to evaluate the following integral:$$\int \frac{{\sin(x)}}{{\sin(x) - \cos(x)}}\,dx$$ Here's my approach so far: 
$$$$I've multiplied the numerator and denominator by  $-csc^3(x)$, resulting in $$\int -\frac{{\csc^2(x)}}{{\cot(x)\csc^2(x) - \csc^2(x)}}\,dx$$
Next I substituted $u = cotx $, giving me $$\frac{{du}}{{dx}} = -csc^2(x), du =  -csc^2(x)dx$$ therefore in $\int -\frac{{\csc^2(x)}}{{\cot(x)\csc^2(x) - \csc^2(x)}}\,dx$ by replacing $cotx$ with $u$,  I obtained,  $$\int \frac{-1}{{u\left(u^2+1\right) - \left(u^2+1\right)}}\,du$$ $$\int (\frac{1}{{4\left(u+1\right)}} - \frac{1}{{4\left(u-1\right)}} - \frac{1}{{2\left(u-1\right)^2}})\,du$$

I would greatly appreciate any insights or techniques that could help me make progress with this integral. Are there specific strategies or mathematical tools that I should consider? Are there any useful properties or identities related to this type of expression?

Thank you for your attention and assistance.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: why is my question still closed? can anyone tell me the reason

Comment: You improved it only 40min ago. You had to wait for 4 votes for its reopening. Done.

Comment: It's only one vote away from being reopened.

Comment: Your question is not clear. I didn't check your computations but it seems you reached the goal. What "progress with this integral" do you need? Can't you integrate $\int (\frac{1}{{4\left(u+1\right)}} - \frac{1}{{4\left(u-1\right)}} - \frac{1}{{2\left(u-1\right)^2}})\,du?$

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Done. Thanks to you,  I learnt it only requires 4 votes.

Comment: Jayadrata: Again, what was your question? The "solution-verification" tag was added by @ÁtilaCorreia. Be *that* your question or be it not, please edit your post to clarify it.

Comment: If I can ask a question: you have multiplied by $-\csc^3(x)$, but what's wrong with a simple $\sec(x)$? :-)

Comment: @AnneBauval I thought it wasn't gonna work out in the end and so didn't do the integration. How stupid of me!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Alternatively, you can proceed as follows:

\begin{align*}
\int\frac{\sin(x)}{\sin(x) - \cos(x)}\mathrm{d}x & = \frac{1}{2}\int\frac{2\sin(x)}{\sin(x) - \cos(x)}\mathrm{d}x\\\\
& = \frac{1}{2}\int\frac{(\sin(x) - \cos(x)) + (\sin(x) + \cos(x))}{\sin(x) - \cos(x)}\mathrm{d}x\\\\
& = \frac{x}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\int\frac{(\sin(x) - \cos(x))'}{\sin(x) - \cos(x)}\mathrm{d}x\\\\
& = \frac{x}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\ln\left(\sin(x) - \cos(x)\right) + C
\end{align*}

Comment: thank you very much your process was so much simpler

Comment: that should be sin(x) + cos(x) instead of (sin(x)−cos(x)), anyway thanks again.

Comment: @JayadrataBanerjee you are welcome ! I am glad to help.

Comment: quite beautiful!

Answer (score 3):

It is not clear what you are asking for (see comments) but if it is a verification of your solution, here is one. You [did very well with your substitution choice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bioche%27s_rules), and were quite near to the solution. I only have three remarks.

1. You did a small sign mistake when you  "obtained, $\int \frac{\color{red}-1}{{u\left(u^2+1\right) - \left(u^2+1\right)}}\,du$": it should be
   $$\int \frac{\color{green}+1}{{u\left(u^2+1\right) - \left(u^2+1\right)}}\,du.$$
2. Next, your partial fraction decomposition was wrong. The correct one is:
   $$\frac1{\left(u-1\right)\left(u^2+1\right)}=\frac12\left(\frac1{u-1}-\frac{u+1}{u^2+1}\right).$$
3. Incomprehensibly, you did not dare integrating it.
   $$\begin{align}\frac12\int\left(\frac1{u-1}-\frac{u+1}{u^2+1}\right)du&=\frac12\left(\ln|u-1|-\frac12\ln\left(u^2+1\right)- \arctan u+C\right)\\&=\frac12\left(\ln\frac{|u-1|}{\sqrt{u^2+1}}+ \operatorname{arccot}u+D\right)\qquad(D=C-\frac\pi2)\\&=\frac12\Big(\ln|\cos x-\sin x|+x+D\Big).\end{align}$$

Comment: thank you very much for pointing out my errors and the solution

Answer (score 2):

Let
$$ A=\int \frac{{\sin(x)}}{{\sin(x) - \cos(x)}}\,dx, B=\int \frac{{\cos(x)}}{{\sin(x) - \cos(x)}}\,dx. $$
Clearly
$$ A-B=\int \;dx=x+C_1. \tag1$$
Note
$$ A=-\int \frac{1}{{\sin(x) - \cos(x)}}\,d\cos(x), B=\int \frac{1}{{\sin(x) - \cos(x)}}\,d\sin(x) $$
and hence
$$ B+A=\int \frac{1}{{\sin(x) - \cos(x)}}\,d(\sin(x)-\cos(x))=\ln|\sin(x)-\cos(x)|+C_2. \tag2$$
From (1) and (2), it is easy to obtain $A$. In fact,
$$ A=\frac12 x+\frac12\ln|\sin(x)-\cos(x)|+C. $$

Answer (score 1):

Use the substitution $x=\frac{\pi}{4}+v \Rightarrow dx=dv$

Now use the following facts:
$$\begin{aligned}
&\sin\left(x+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)=\frac{\sin x+\cos x}{\sqrt{2}} \\
& \cos \left(x+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)=\frac{\cos x-\sin x}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{aligned}$$

So we get $$\begin{aligned}
I= & \int \frac{\sin x d x}{\sin x-\cos x}=\int \frac{\left(\frac{\sin v+\cos v}{\sqrt{2}}\right) d v}{\left(\frac{2 \sin v}{\sqrt{2}}\right)} \\
& \Rightarrow I=\frac{1}{2} \int \frac{\sin v}{\sin v} d v+\frac{1}{2} \int \cot v d v \\
& \Rightarrow I=\frac{v}{2}+\frac{1}{2} \ln |\sin v|+C
\end{aligned}$$
Where $v=x-\frac{\pi}{4}$.

Method $2:$

Use the identities
$$\begin{aligned}
\cos ^2 x-\sin ^2 x & =\cos 2 x=1-2 \sin ^2 x \\
\sin 2 x & =2 \sin x \cos x
\end{aligned}$$

$$\begin{aligned}
f(x) & =\frac{\sin x}{\sin x-\cos x}=\frac{-\sin x(\cos x+\sin x)}{\cos ^2 x-\sin ^2 x} \\
& \Rightarrow f(x)=\frac{-1}{2}\left(\frac{2 \sin x \cos x+2 \sin ^2 x}{\cos 2x}\right) \\
& \Rightarrow f(x)=\frac{-1}{2}\left(\frac{\sin 2x+1-\cos 2 x}{\cos 2 x}\right) \\
& \Rightarrow f(x)=\frac{-1}{2}(\tan (2 x)+\sec (2 x)-1)
\end{aligned}$$

Hope you can proceed from here.

Comment: You gave two methods. Damn!

Answer (score 1):

Multiplying the numerator and the denominator of the integrand by $\sin x+\cos x$ we get the integral of $\frac12-\frac12\sec2x-\frac12\tan2x$ which is
$$\frac x2-\frac14\ln|\sec2x+\tan2x|-\frac14\ln|\cos2x|+c$$
and
$$\frac x2-\frac14\ln|1+\sin2x|+c.$$

Answer (score -1):

$1/2(\ln |\sin(x)-\cos(x)|)+x/2+c$

$\sin(x)$ can be written as $1/2(2\sin(x))$ and then $2\sin(x)$ should be written as $\sin(x)+\cos(x)+\sin(x)-\cos(x)$. Then integrating we get the above result.

Comment: How does your solution differ from Atia Correia?